# Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type

Tags: swift, protocols, opaque-types

I have a protocol

```
protocol doSomethingProtocol {
    associatedtype someType
}
```

then i have class that is implementing this protocol

```
class doSomethingClass : doSomethingProtocol {
    typealias someType = Int
}
```

Now i want to use this protocol as a reference in some other class

```
class someClass : ObservableObject {

    private var reference : doSomethingProtocol

}
```

Now i cannot do this as `doSomethingProtocol` has an associatedtype. So i decide to use `some`

```
class someClass : ObservableObject {

    private var reference : some doSomethingProtocol

    init(){
         reference = doSomethingClass()
    }

}
```

However this doesn't work. I get the error `Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type`. Why ? I am giving it initializer expression in the class init.

However when i do something like this

```
class someClass : ObservableObject {

    private var reference : some doSomethingProtocol = doSomethingClass()

    init(){}

}
```

I get no error messages and it compiles. Why, what is the difference between the two.

Comment: In first case type undefined (ie. generic) so concrete cannot be assigned to generic - error, in second case type is inferred during initialisation explicitly. Actually it is not clear what do you try to achieve - you cannot use `doSomethingProtocol` w/o associated type specialization.

Comment: @Asperi Sorry i didn't get what you are trying to say. Why the compiler cannot infer in first case after all i am explicitly assigning it an object in the initialiser.

Answer (score 10):

> Now i cannot do this as doSomethingProtocol has an associatedtype. So i decide to use `some`

This is where you went wrong. Opaque (`some`) types solve a completely different problem than protocols with associated types. An opaque type is *concrete*. It is one, specific type, known at compile time, returned by a function. It just is not known to the caller of the function. It is completely known to the compiler.

```
var reference : some DoSomethingProtocol
```

Given this information, what *concrete* type is `reference`? It's not known. It's hinted at by the behavior of `init`, but it's not known to always be that. (Even more so since this is a class that could override its `init` and assign some other type.)

What you're trying to do is done this way:

```
private var reference : DoSomethingClass
```

This defines SomeType == DoSomethingClass, and allows DoSomethingClass to conform to DoSomethingProtocol.

If you're trying to avoid nailing down the type that DoSomethingClass uses here, that's not possible. To conform to a protocol with an associated type, you must provide a concrete type that can be determined at compile time.

Given the problems your running into, I suspect that DoSomethingClass is incorrectly designed, and you don't really want a PAT (protocol with associated type) here. You probably want a generic, or composition, or possibly closures. It is possible (though unlikely) that you want a type eraser. But you don't want opaque types.

(Please capitalize your types. Having leading lowercase for a type is very confusing in Swift.)